# IOS Flash and ringing while app is running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are building an application that we would like to have running in the background. What I am not sure about is what are we limited to when it comes to running in the background.

Imagine an app that is like tag. UserA and UserB are both running the app. UserA opens the app uses the app then switches to a new app. UserB opens the app then clicks the lock screen button and shoves phone in is pocket.

When the idea of the app is when the UserA and UserB get within 100 feet or less of each other their phones start ring/vibrate and setoff the camera flash (assume the phones are in the stat
they were left in above).  Is this possible ring/vibrate/flash possible if the app is not open and being viewed by the users?

Any links/references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to set off the flash when your app is in the background, because to do that you basically are firing up the camera. Apple knows that users don't like apps being able to take pictures while in the background, so this behavior is not possible.

For the other oath, however - where you are wanting to check if they are within 100ft, you would want your app to be running in the background gathering location coordinates (possible) and securely uploading them to your server.

You could then send a push notification to each phone, but you will not be able to make them sound for more than about 15s at a time.

Comment: Can you not turn the flash on and off like in all the flashlight apps?   
   http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/flashlight-application-using-the-iphone-led.html

Comment: You can toggle the flash when your app is in the foreground - that's just turning the camera on and off. But in the background, you can't do this.